# Python Pandas incorrect date count

Tags: python, pandas, date, count

Working with the following python pandas dataframe "df":

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_ID  | Item_ID
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X8973
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X2468
ABC           2017-05-22-658    X2906
ABC           2017-05-22-757    X8790
ABC           2017-07-13-864    X8790     
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2346
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2468
```

I want to count the transactions to have in a column denoted, when it's the client's 1st transaction, 2nd transaction and so forth by date. (If there are two transactions on the same day, I am counting them both as the same count, since I don't have the time, so I don't know which one came first - basically treating them as one transaction).

```
#get the date out of the Transaction_ID string
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Transaction_ID.str[:10])

#calculate the transaction number
df['trans_nr'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID',"Transaction_ID", df['date'].dt.year]).cumcount()+1
```

Unfortunately, this is my output with the code above:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_ID  | Item_ID | date        | trans_nr
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X8973     2017-04-12     1
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X2468     2017-04-12     2
ABC           2017-05-22-658    X2906     2017-05-22     1
ABC           2017-05-22-757    X8790     2017-05-22     1
ABC           2017-07-13-864    X8790     2017-07-13     1
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2346     2017-08-11     1
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2468     2017-08-11     2
```

Which is incorrect, this is the correct output I am looking for:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_ID  | Item_ID | date        | trans_nr
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X8973     2017-04-12     1
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X2468     2017-04-12     1
ABC           2017-05-22-658    X2906     2017-05-22     2
ABC           2017-05-22-757    X8790     2017-05-22     2
ABC           2017-07-13-864    X8790     2017-07-13     3
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2346     2017-08-11     1
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2468     2017-08-11     1
```

Maybe the logic should be based only on Customer_ID and date (without Transaction_ID)?

I tried this

```
df['trans_nr'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID','date').cumcount()+1
```

But it also counts incorrectly.

Comment: Can you explain the trans_nr = 1 for the seconrd records.  When I run your code, trans_nr for the second record  = 2.  i get [1 2 1 1 1 1 2]  Not [1 1 1 2 2 1 2]

Comment: Sorry - I was experimenting with the counts and pasted the wrong one - I need to get [ 1 1 2 2 3 1 1] though

Comment: Why is  the second record 1?  What is different about the first two records, I see only Item_ID?

Comment: Correct - it's two different items - but the same transaction on the same day; so it should still be counted as the customer's 1st transaction

Comment: Why is records number 4 equal to 2 when the record three equals 2 for a different transation_id in your expected results?

Comment: the logic should be based on date and customer_id only - If there are two transactions on the same day, I am counting them both as the same count, since I don't have the time, so I don't know which one came first - basically treating them as one transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df['trans_nr'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID', df['date'].dt.year])['date']\
                   .transform(lambda x: (x.diff() != pd.Timedelta('0 days')).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
 Customer_ID  Transaction_ID Item_ID       date  trans_nr
0         ABC  2017-04-12-333   X8973 2017-04-12         1
1         ABC  2017-04-12-333   X2468 2017-04-12         1
2         ABC  2017-05-22-658   X2906 2017-05-22         2
3         ABC  2017-05-22-757   X8790 2017-05-22         2
4         ABC  2017-07-13-864   X8790 2017-07-13         3
5         BCD  2017-08-11-879   X2346 2017-08-11         1
6         BCD  2017-08-11-879   X2468 2017-08-11         1
```

Comment: Might be simple with ngroups.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dual groupby` with `ngroup()` i.e

```
df['trans_nr'] = df.groupby('Customer_ID').apply(lambda x : \
                x.groupby([x['date'].dt.date]).ngroup()+1).values
```

```
 Customer_ID  Transaction_ID Item_ID       date  trans_nr
0         ABC  2017-04-12-333   X8973 2017-04-12         1
1         ABC  2017-04-12-333   X2468 2017-04-12         1
2         ABC  2017-05-22-658   X2906 2017-05-22         2
3         ABC  2017-05-22-757   X8790 2017-05-22         2
4         ABC  2017-07-13-864   X8790 2017-07-13         3
5         BCD  2017-08-11-879   X2346 2017-08-11         1
6         BCD  2017-08-11-879   X2468 2017-08-11         1
```

Comment: Your solution use two groupbys instead of one.  I think this will be close to two time slower that mine.  Can you condense it into one groupby using ngroup?

Comment: I agree since it was suppose to reset I used twice. Let me try

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to drop duplicate values before making the cumulative count:

```
trans_nr = (df
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['Customer_ID', 'date'])
        .set_index(['Customer_ID', 'date'])
        .groupby(level='Customer_ID')
        .cumcount() + 1
    )
df.set_index(['Customer_ID', 'date'], inplace=True)
df['trans_nr'] = trans_nr
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

To get the transaction number, you first remove rows with duplicate `Customer_ID` and `date` values.  Then you set their index using `Customer_ID` and `date` (for merging later) and perform your `groupby` and `cumcount`.  This produces a series whose values are the cumulative count for each `Customer_ID` and `date`.

You also set the index for the original dataframe (again to allow for merging).  Then you simply assign the `trans_nr` series to a column in `df`.  The indices take care of the merging logic.